Alinear estos contenedores o tarjetas
Necesito que en estos contenedores o tarjetas me quedan alineadas horizontalmente, tal que la primera me queda en la izquierda, la segunda en el centro y la tercera en la izquierda.
Éste es el código css que estoy usando:


.container-players {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Bienvenido, Usuario!</h1>
<div class="container-players">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200/" alt="Cristiano Ronaldo">
  <h3><strong>Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro</strong></h3>
  <p>texto informativo</p>
</div>
<div class="container-players">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200/" alt="James Rodriguez">
  <h3><strong>James Rodriguez</strong></h3>
  <p>texto informativo</p>
</div>
<a href="logout.php">Cerrar sesión</a> `



Pero no encuentro la manera de alinear esto. Se ve así:


No está alineado porque te falta Messi . Podrías solucionarlo con flexbox. Puedes cargar el HTML también?

Bienvenido, !
div CR7


Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro
texto informativo
    
Div james


James Rodriguez
texto informativo

Cerrar sesión    Esto es un resumen de mi codigo html

@Andres si subes código, edita la publicación, no lo agregues acá en los comentarios.

Lo que hice fue crear un contenedor que englobe a todas las "cards" que tienes de jugadores. A ese contenedor le di la clase container-players que estabas usando para cada una de las "cards" (ya que semánticamente lo que he definido es un contenedor de jugadores). Luego a cada "card" de un jugador le cambié el nombre a la clase para que se ajuste más a lo que representa (le di la clase player). Hasta ahí los cambios en el HTML.
En el CSS lo que hice fue decir que el contenedor de cards de jugadores sea display: flex, con lo que conseguimos que las 3 cards de jugadores que contiene sean renderizadas en la misma línea. Luego, a través de justify-content: espace-between conseguimos que el espacio en blanco que no ocupan las "cards" dentro de la fila, sea colocado entre medias de cada una de las "cards" para que de esta manera la primera quede a la izquierda, la segunda en el centro y la tercera a la derecha).


.container-players {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.player {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
}
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Bienvenido, Usuario!</h1>
<div class="container-players">
  <div class="player">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200/" alt="Cristiano Ronaldo">
    <h3><strong>Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro</strong></h3>
    <p>texto informativo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="player">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200/" alt="James Rodriguez">
    <h3><strong>James Rodriguez</strong></h3>
    <p>texto informativo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="player">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200/" alt="Barry Bonds">
    <h3><strong>Barry Bonds</strong></h3>
    <p>texto informativo</p>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="logout.php">Cerrar sesión</a> `




Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya esta como lo queria.
